# Hiding parts of images falling outside the page

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using an image that it a lot bigger than my page and I don't want to make it smaller. Problem is, I see it entirely in my inDesign window, not just the part fitting into my document, but the rest of the image too, extending far beyond it.

Is there a way to hide this part? I don't need it and it distracts me too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **Selection Tool** (black arrow) to click a handle on the *Image Frame* and reduce the size of the frame. This doesn't change the image at all. It merely alters what is visible.

[image]

You can also hit the <kbd>**W**</kbd> key to change the screen mode to `Preview` (View > Screen Mode > Preview). This hides everything *except* the actual page content.

You may find benefit in checking out some [**basic InDesign tutorials**](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/tutorials.html).

Comment: (Note how Scott makes sure not to crop all the way up to the *page edge*, but to the bleed edge instead. Allowing for bleed is standard practice in everything that goes to print.)